# Writing Probability distribution in terms of a trace over a density matrix

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I have been given and expression for a probability distribution precisely,

$P(x,y,z)= \sum_\lambda P(x|y,\lambda)P(y|\lambda,z)P(z)P(\lambda)$

and I have been asked to show that the above expression can be written in the forma of the following (with correct changes)

$P(x,y,z)= Tr(\rho_{AB}(E_A^{x|y} \otimes E_B^{y|z}))P(z)$

where $\rho_{AB}, E_A^{x|y}, E_B^{y|z}$ are the density matrix and POVM’s on system AB.

I have no clue of even how the trace comes into picture. I have no clue as to how the first expression can be simplified to get a trace, leave alone getting the whole expression correctly.

---

***[Cross-posted on quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16073/55)***

Comment: @glS are you the down voter. If so please explain the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly clear from the question exactly what you want but here's maybe something to get you started.

If you define some density matrices $\rho_A^\lambda$ such that $\mathrm{Tr}[\rho_A^{\lambda} E_A^{x|y}] = p(x|y,\lambda)$ and similarly define $\rho_B^{\lambda}$ such that $\mathrm{Tr}[\rho_B^{\lambda} E_B^{y|z}] = p(y|z,\lambda)$. Then you can define the joint state
$$
\rho_{AB} = \sum_\lambda p(\lambda) \rho_A^\lambda \otimes \rho_B^\lambda.
$$

Then you have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Tr}[\rho_{AB} (E_A^{x|y}\otimes E_B^{y|z})]p(z) &= \mathrm{Tr}[(\sum_\lambda p(\lambda) \rho_A^\lambda \otimes \rho_B^\lambda) (E_A^{x|y}\otimes E_B^{y|z})]p(z) \\
&= \sum_\lambda p(\lambda)\mathrm{Tr}[(\rho_A^\lambda \otimes \rho_B^\lambda) (E_A^{x|y}\otimes E_B^{y|z})]p(z) \\
&= \sum_\lambda p(\lambda)\mathrm{Tr}[\rho_A^\lambda E_A^{x|y}] \mathrm{Tr}[   \rho_B^\lambda E_B^{y|z}]p(z) \\ 
&= \sum_\lambda p(\lambda) p(x|y,\lambda) p(y|z,\lambda) p(z)\\
&= p(x,y,z) 
\end{align*}

Comment: Can it shown the other way, beginning with the probability distribution and showing that it can be written like a trace?

Comment: Because the context requires that a probability distribution can be written in terms of a trace rather than the other way round

Comment: Well then if you take the above construction you need only show that given some set of POVMs $E^{x|y}$ there exist states $\rho^{\lambda}$ such that $\mathrm{Tr}[\rho^{\lambda} E^{x|y}] = p(x|y,\lambda)$.